# Ninja IDE and PyQt >= 4.7 how to configure on windows

Tags: python, pyqt

I tried to configure the PyQt >= 4.7 on windows . but i was unable to configure it with ninja IDE source code, when i trying to run the IDE it gives an error as below:

```
ImportError: No module named PyQt4.QtCore`
```

how to  run the ninja IDE source and configure the PyQt on windows?

Comment: this doesn't look like a programming question...

Comment: @LtWorf if yew ever tried to use QT packages in windows you may see this as a  programming question

Comment: I did, but that's more an "how do i install qt on windows?" kind of question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've installed Ninja IDE on two Windows machines, a Windows 7 machine with only [standard Python 3 installed](http://www.python.org/getit/) where it gives me that error you mentioned.

And a Windows XP machine on which I had [pythonxy](https://code.google.com/p/pythonxy/) which comes with PyQt in a convenient easy to use installer thus it worked without any further troubles.

Answer (score 1):

I am having the same problem on Ubuntu: installing the [PyQt packet from source](http://www.riverbankcomputing.co.uk/software/pyqt/download) solved it. I assume that Ninja-IDE needs these packets to be installed as a prerequisite.